# How to take a user input (from scanner) and convert the entire input into ascii

Tags: java, ascii, stringbuilder

I'm doing a small java RSA Encryption task and i've found myself stuck.

I'm currently using a stringbuilder that takes in a users input and converts it all into ascii however it just gives the exact character (a = 97) for the ascii to be encrypted into something readable it needs to output all characters like this (a = 097).

Any idea how to fix this or is there a better solution for this?

```
 String Secret;

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //opens a scanner, keyboard
 System.out.println("Please Enter what you want to encrypt: "); //prompt the user
 Secret = input.next(); //store the input from the user

 String str = Secret;  // or anything else

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();// do 1 character at a time. / convert each to ascii one at a time and then, have each2 values equate to 11 digit or "value"
 for (char c : str.toCharArray( ))
 sb.append((byte)c);// bit array could be easier as this could make it difficult to decrypt

     BigInteger m = new BigInteger(sb.toString());

 System.out.println(m);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is printing a formatted string for your integers adding leading zeros

You'll need to use System.out.format instead of println. format is a method with the following signature

```
public PrintStream format(Locale l, String format, Object... args)
```

Or, using the JDK **default** Locale

```
public PrintStream format(String format, Object... args)
```

So you can write something like that:

```
int a = 97;
System.out.format("%03d%n",a);   //  -->  "097"
```

But you can also use the **C Style** printf method

```
 System.out.printf("%03d\n",a);   //  -->  "097"
```

This does more or less the same that:

```
String aWithLeadingZeros =String.format("%03d",a); 
System.out.println(aWithLeadingZeros); //  -->  "097"
```

This is how to format each ASCII code to a 3 digits with leading zero string and add all String to the StringBuffer

```
String secret = "hello world!"; // or anything else B)
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : secret.toCharArray()) {
    // int casting wrap the char value 'c' to the corresponding ASCII code
    sb.append(String.format("%03d",(int)c));                        
}
System.out.println(sb); // -> 104101108108111032119111114108100033
// 'H' is 104, 'e' is 101, 'l' is 108, and so on..
```

Comment: Will this automatically take whatever characters inputted and output the correct number/numbers ?

Comment: Any printable char (with a corresponding ASCII code) should work

Comment: You are my saviour! thank you so much (all is nice and functional now):)